# How to test the payload of a POST request?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Suppose I have a method that sends a `POST` request with JSON data. What would be a good way to test the JSON payload? I know how to mock requests and monkey patch the response in general (I'm using [HTTPretty](http://falcao.it/HTTPretty/) for mocking responses), but how could the payload of a `POST` (or `PUT` and others for that matter) be tested?

```
def update_progress(self):
    # fetch all interesting stuff
    interesting = ...
    payload = list()
    for i in interesting:
        # do something
        payload += ...

    self.api.post('v1/update', params=payload)
```

where `self.api.post` is a custom method for sending a `POST` by calling `requests.request`.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like `json schema`?

Comment: No, I'd like to test that my method behaves correctly and produces the right payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it out now. It can be done with HTTPretty. It keeps track of the requests so the body of the requests could just be read using `httpretty.last_request().body`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [cassette](https://github.com/uber/cassette) module made by Uber and used by many including tweepy to test your HTTP requests payloads.